# BizTalk: Map failure in orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-mapper, biztalk-orchestrations

I have a legacy code where a transform is applied to an incoming document -- plain XML schema. It is being mapped to request for executing a SQL PROC.

So although it shows error source as  Source: Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline, on the admin console query hub it is  seen as suspended process at orchestration and not at the send port which does the SQL operation of executing the SQL PROC? Can someone explain this? There is no clue in fixing the issue. On reprocess it does work. But this happens very often

Now this transform fails. But interestingly it shows this in event log:

> Exception type: COMException
>       Source: Microsoft.BizTalk.Pipeline
>       Target Site: Void Read(Byte*, Int32, Int32*)
>       The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the 
>       exception occured
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IStream.Read(Byte* pv, Int32 cb, Int32* pcbRead)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.StreamViewOfIStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.MarkableForwardOnlyEventingReadStream.ReadInternal(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.EventingReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.StreamEncodingDetector._read(Stream stm, Byte[] buff)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.StreamEncodingDetector._detectStreamEncoding(Stream stm)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.StreamEncodingDetector.CreateStream(Stream stm, Encoding& encoding)
>       at Microsoft.BizTalk.Streaming.StreamEncodingDetector.CreateStreamReader(Stream stm)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.UnderlyingPart.CreateXmlReader()
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.RuntimeTypes.XmlRewritingContentFactoryState._createStreamOrReader(String& encoding, Boolean wantEncoding, Boolean wantReader)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.GetStream(String& encoding, Boolean wantEncoding)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Value.RetrieveAs(Type t)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.ProtectedRetrieveAs(Type t)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.RetrieveAs(Type t)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Part.get_Stream()
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.Service.ApplyTransform(Type mapRef, Object[] 
> outParams, Object[] inParams)
>       at MyProcess.segment1(StopConditions stopOn)
>       at Microsoft.XLANGs.Core.SegmentScheduler.RunASegment(Segment s, StopConditions stopCond, Exception& exp)

EDIT 1: ADDITIONAL INFO
 the map does not use any custom functoid. It just plainly links one field on the source to another field on the destination (destination is a sqlproc schema. i have observed the problem even with smaller files like around 400 kb etc

Comment: Have you tried moving the map from the Orchestration to the Port?  Is there anything unusual or special in the map?  e.g. Custom Functoids, calls to external systems etc.  How large is the XML?

Comment: See a similar error in this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/af6fa8fd-09de-4a51-b563-916fce100dad/processing-large-messages-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: Also I take it this is also you https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4cf629a7-ee6f-4f3a-aecf-90c80b6e5775/map-failure-in-orchestration?forum=biztalkgeneral     If it is, 11 MB is rather large.

Comment: Thank you Dijkgraaf. Out of the two links you shared the later is the one created by me. The problem is still not solved, so posted here. Later on testing on DEV environment I found out that I see the problem even for smaller files, so it need not necessarily be a large file issue. Moreover, the occurrence of this error is very random and very rare. It gets processed on reprocessing it.

Comment: If you could answer some of my questions in the first comment (by editing your question to add details), it might go some way towards an answer, otherwise we are just left guessing as to what the problem is.   If it is random, it may be due to load on the server at the time, have you done PAL logging and Analysis?

Comment: am sorry, I missed out on that. the map does not use any custom functoid. It just plainly links one field on the source to another field on the destination (destination is a sqlproc schema). Yes it is random. But i don't think its due to load, because DEV environments do not have any load. But i will exploreon those lines too